# Titlesec: Redefinition of sectioning command leads to endless execution of latex

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, tufte

I'm new at TeX.SX and I hope I do everything correct.

To avoid answers like "Why do you do this?" I'd first like to describe briefly what I want: I'm developing a class based on `tufte-book`, which implements `\subsubsection` to throw an error. However, I'd like to provide the `\subsubsection` in my class. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to use the `\titleformat` macro to style the subsubsection since `tufte-book` uses `titlesec`. My first try was:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\makeatletter
% Copy the definition from book.cls
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
% The following macro is called at the very end of titlesec.sty.
% If I uncomment it, the latex process runs forever.

%\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

% Without the optional argument, it works...
% However, if you make the following line a comment...
\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}

% ... the access to subsubsection using the titlesec API doesn't work anymore 
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{%
  \fontsize{36}{42}\selectfont%
}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[]


\begin{document}
  \subsection{bar}
  \subsubsection{foo}
\end{document}
```

After investigating `titlesec.sty` a bit, the MWE can be reduced to using the same call of `\titleclass` twice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% runs forever
%\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

% works
\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}

% Does not make sense, but works
%\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}[\paragraph]

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{%
  \fontsize{36}{42}\selectfont%
}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[]


\begin{document}
  \subsection{bar}
  \subsubsection{foo}
\end{document}
```

While I believe that encountering an infinite loop is a good sign to have found a bug, I do neither find it nor I find any comments or threads on this issue in the net. I would agree that using the same `\titleclass` definition twice is something obscure, but it should at least result in an error instead of something infinite. Does anyone see the (potential) bug or, more likely, my mistake?

Comment: It isn't to do with using it twice. It is to do with not trying to redefine it as itself, I think. `\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]` tries to create a new level below `\subsection` called `\subsubsection`. But there is already a level here. It is called `\subsubsection`. I haven't gone through the code but `titlesec` must insert a level when there is already a lower level. So it must try to also switch the level of the lower level, but that's `\subsubsection`. `\titleclass` is supposed to either just switch the style or create a new level. You are trying to recreate one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE, by the way ;)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than copying the definition from `book`, you have to supply the forgotten one given by `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\ttl@straightclass{subsubsection}}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
  {\fontsize{36}{42}\selectfont}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
  []

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{B}
\subsection{bar}
\subsubsection{foo}
\paragraph{C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem in both cases is that

```
\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
```

tries to move section levels under `\subsection` down before inserting the new `\subsubsection` level.  A way to work around this is to define a level with a new name, e.g. ssubsection, and then put `\subsubsection` to be a copy of `\ssubsection`; because of optional arguments etc. you will need to use `\LetLtxMacro` from the package of the same name to do this:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\titleclass{\ssubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{ssubsection}

\titleformat{\ssubsection}{%
  \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\selectfont%
}{\thessubsection}{1em}{}[]

\titlespacing{\ssubsection}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}

\LetLtxMacro\subsubsection\ssubsection

\begin{document}
  \subsection{Bar} Text.
  \subsubsection{Foo} Text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had this solution in mind, too. However, it's only a workaround. Using the solution posted by egreg is more clean, I think.