# larger `tufte-handout` file which does not produce pdf (but any part of it does)

Tags: luatex, tufte

I have extended the `tufte-latex` documentclass `tufte-handout` with a `subsubsection` as

```
\titleclass{\subsubsection}{straight}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}%
[hang]% shape
{\normalfont\large\itshape}% format applied to label+text
{\thesubsubsection}% label
{1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
{}% before the title body
[]% after the title body
```

following advice found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389608/copying-subsection-style-to-subsubsection). I have now a larger file (with tables, using `longtable` and `booktabs` and get an error and no pdf output (with lualatex)

```
(./025players_2ok.aux)
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {section}{Kommentar zur Datenla 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.64 \begin{document}
                   
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

I have tried to produce a MWE, but whenever I cut a piece away, I get results with some error messages and cannot produce a minimal example to produce the error. The setup is the same as in [other questions I have asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689896/documentclass-tufte-latex-produces-error-messages-with-biblatex?noredirect=1#comment1711818_689896) and I fear it is a related problem. Any suggestions what I can change?

Comment: well the error is when writing the contentline for the toc. So check the content of the \section that is mentioned in the error.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - Thank you for the hint how to debug. I removed all section heads (they seem to cause the problem) and completed the `renewcommand` from `tufte-common.def` (similar to your previous recommendations).  Now it runs without errors, (warnings for margins only) but does not produce a pdf. If I cut a part of the text, it runs `normally` and produces the pdf.where can i look now?

Comment: play detective and find the place where it breaks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I found a MWE with only a few lines. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689997/a-small-text-with-emph-in-a-tufte-handout-produces-a-segmentation-fault. I do not understand enough about lualatex to understand it.