# A small text with `\emph` in a `tufte-handout` produces a segmentation fault

Tags: luatex, tufte

A `tufte-handout` produces a `sementation fault` for a minimal text including an `\emph`. When I remove surrounding text, it compiles with lualatex. An `\emph` at another spot works ok as well. Running in documentclass `article` works as well.

What causes the fault?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,nobib] %openright to force parts and chapter to start right
         {tufte-handout}  %testhandout  testzwei 
        
\usepackage{microtype} 
\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[200]{#1}}% 
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[50]{#1}}%
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\allcapsspacing{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
```

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % was originally lost,
% readded per comment from Ulrike Fisher

```
% -- -- --- ----------  ----             ----        ---------------
\begin{document}
 
some text \emph{other text} is ok (alone)

Ein besseres Bild der Realwirtschaft bieten wohl die weniger verzerrten
Werte für die\emph{Haushaltsausgaben}
pro Kopf. Hier liegen die Industrieländer näher zusammen und die Werte
scheinen mir realistischer.

\end{document}
```

The log file in a terminal is

```
    This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./025_6_1.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2023-01-16>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-handout.cls
Document Class: tufte-handout 2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Tufte-handout class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hardwrap/hardwrap.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paralist/paralist.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sauerj/optparams.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-de-1996.
tex UTF-8 German hyphenation patterns (reformed orthography)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-de-1996.
tex
German Hyphenation Patterns (Reformed Orthography, 2006) `dehyphn-x' 2021-02-26
 (WL))))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/de/babel-ngerman.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [openany].

(./025_6_1.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(./025_6_1.out) (./025_6_1.out)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: luatex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

Package microtype Warning: Unable to apply patch `footnote' on input line 42.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-Palatino.cfg)Segmentation fault
frank@santafe:~/bakedHomepage/Essays/Worldorder/p20situation$
```

Comment: No problem here using Vanilla TeX Live 2023 or Vanilla TeX Live 2022. So maybe a problem with your machine or maybe with the debian binaries of TeX Live 2022.

Comment: works fine in windows too

Comment: I will check on another computer! thank you for information

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  -   i checked on three installations (independently installed, but essentially from two Debian distributions). The same segfault. The moment I change the most minimal thing (add  or delete a few characters), it goes away. A fluke... Thank you for the help!

Comment: well your example doesn't tell the truth. It wouldn't load ngerman. With ngerman I get segfault too in texlive 2022, but in texlive 2023 it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Indeed, i lost this crucial piece in editing. i will install the texlive 2023 asap. Thank you a lot for discovering my omission.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer   -  With texlive-2023 installed the example and the book (>100 pages) run without error.  I am really impressed that you figured out that I left out `mgerman`. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing strange with TL 2022 for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem disappeared with an update to a current distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, as @UlrikeFischer pointed out, with an old version of texlive. Install `texlive-2023` and the problem is solved.